# Datatables Datatools not properly displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

[image]

As you can see the Datatools `[Copy, CSV, Excel, PDF, Print]` tools is displayed that way that it forces the Search Filter to go to the middle.

I believe my code is correct I am inserting that tool before the `dataTables_wrapper` which is existing. The Datatools should go to the top and Search Filter should be aligned horizontally with the Show Entries Tool.

```
var t =  $('#formList').DataTable({ "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]] });
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(t);
$( tt.fnContainer()).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');
```

My HTML

```
<table id="formList" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="6"> <center>Form Information<center></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Form #</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Plan Holder</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>
```

The Datatables Tool should align like this:

[image]

Comment: Thart sounds very weird. Perhaps you have some CSS that makes some of the controls to float around? Can you replicate it in this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/nz2e7ecr/ {dataTables, tableTools, bootstrap}

Comment: @davidkonrad yeah i dunno what is happening i dont have any custom css on it just plain bootstrap. on my other one its working fine but this one is not